# Откуда береться недостающий код

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image: Ну вот собственно проблема]

Как вы видите pandas я не импортировал, переменной bigdata нет, а cvs файлы в другой папке.
Я уже удалил и все чекпоинты, и этот файл в котором код был, заново пишу и опять оно работает..
Помогите пожалуйста, я только начинаю изучать пайтон и юпитер скачал дня два назад.

Comment: У вас ячейка 56 раз запускалась, если раньше вы в ней запускали импорт pandas, то он все еще импортирован, т.к. это происходило в том же самом процессе Python. Если закрыть консоль интерпретатора и запустить jupyter заново, то перестанет работать.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.